# After updating Xcode, simple sprite kit statements not working

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode9, swift4

I am learning game programming using Spritekit. After making the most recent update to Xcode, everything seems to have gone awry. Games that I had written with Swift 3 are not functioning. Some sprites are not being loaded.

I created a new project just to test. I included a simple png file and tried to initialise an SKSpriteNode object and called addChild. Nothing appears. Node count is zero.

I would appreciate any help on this. What could be going wrong?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    print ("am in didmoveto now")
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "martianbackground")

    addChild(background)
  }
}
```

The print statement does not show up. Node count is 0. So no child is added. didMove is not getting called for some reason. Breakpoints seem to have no effect.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print ("view has loaded it would appear")

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You’ll have to post your code.::

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I get this in the console log:

```
am in didmoveto now
2017-10-08 22:13:09.721183+0100 <project_name>[4608:2085947] SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "martianbackground"
```

the simulator screen shows a big, red 'X' in the centre and the node count is 2.

Are you sure that this 'GameScene' is actually being loaded by your GameViewController?

Comment: Hello, The big red X is because you don't have a graphic image labelled background. I did not include assets in my code. That was assumed. But from your console log I see you did get into did move. In my case Console is logging nothing. didMove is not getting called for some reason. so no code inside the didMove is getting executed.

Comment: Yes - I mentioned getting the ‘X’ because it indicates that the code is working - I just didn’t bother importing any images into the test project. So as this code works, the most likely problem is your `GameViewController.swift` file. Can you post the code for that?

Comment: So, basically, in your case didMove is getting called. And in my case it is not!

Comment: Yes I will. Incidentally, the print statement inside GameViewController logs just fine!

Comment: `didMoveTo` *always* gets called. Unless the scene you are in has not, in fact, been moved to the view.

Comment: That is what I thought also! Anyway, please see the edited post above.

Comment: If you put a `print` before the `presentScene`, does that do anything?

Comment: That's auto generated code! I've never seen it fail!

Comment: Is your `GameScene` class in a file named `GameScene.swift`?

Comment: Try changing the `if let scene...` to a simple `let scene` and see if either Xcode complains about something or if you get a run-time error.

Comment: I get an error on that line that says "Cannot invoke initialiser for type 'SKScene' with an argument list of type '(fileNamed: String, () -> ())'

Comment: Version 9. You’be removed an `if` so you’ll also have to remove the {...} enclosing the statements after the `if...let` down to after the `presentScene`

Comment: My guess is something changed in the storyboard so that the view is not an SKView anymore

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks. 

I get a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on that line during runtime.

Comment: And log says 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-10-10 18:56:34.187723+0530 Swift4SpritekitTrial[3427:701772] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Thanks for your comment KnightDragon. Most of the code I am trying is autogenerated. Is this some kind of known issue? Steve's seem to be working though.

Comment: I'd go with Knight's suggestion. Put a `print(self.view)` after you call `super.viewdidLoad` and see if it is an SKView and if not, what it is.

Comment: Hi Knight and Steve. I put a print (self.view) immediately after super.viewdidLoad and got the following console output.

Comment: <SKView: 0x7fa18d018000; frame = (0 0; 736 414); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CAEAGLLayer: 0x60c000039c20>>

Comment: Sorry - printing self.view was a red herring. It’s the scene that’s not loading. SKScene(fileNamed:) returns an optional, and in your case it’s nil. You could try creating a new scene and seeing if you can load that? Or otherwise just check everything really carefully.